# Display a particular column, from data dictionaries

Tags: python, json, flask

My Question- I have a json dataset, which contains 20 rows(arrays), with column data. In my flask app, I want to display only the particular column. So, if I select column "Mag", i want the output of all 3 values of Mag. Can you help me out with it?

Error Flashing:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Dataset:

```
0
:
{MasterID: "1121011005600", RA: "30.00031", DECL: "20.00025", Mag: "21.0222", MagErr: "0.52", …}
1
:
{MasterID: "1121011005600", RA: "29.99994", DECL: "20.00162", Mag: "19.3008", MagErr: "0.21", …}
2
:
{MasterID: "1121011005600", RA: "29.99983", DECL: "20.0016", Mag: "21.0652", MagErr: "0.5", …}
3
:
{MasterID: "1121011005600", RA: "29.99948", DECL: "20.00153", Mag: "19.9838", MagErr: "0.28", …}
```

Code:

```
@app.route('/something', methods = ["POST"])
def something():
    val1 = float(request.json['val1']) #ignore these inputs
    val2 = float(request.json['val2']) #ignore these inputs
    data = request.json['data']
    for i in range (0, len(data)):
         print data['MJD'][i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently indexing a list with a string instead of an int.

Try:

```
for item in data:
    print item['MJD']
```

Comment: yes, it is working. And a side question, if I wish to assign this column a new name, then what should be the ideal thing??